# is there a way to set the navmesh manually, not automatically? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

Is it possible to set navmesh manually in Unity? I am asking because I want to set this surface more precisely.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You can change the voxel size and min region in advanced navmesh bake setting, turning down the voxel size will make it more accurate, and the min region will allow smaller areas to be baked. [Unity Api](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/nav-AdvancedSettings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create empty objects with NavMeshModifierVolume component, set Area Type to Not Walkable (Edit Volume as you do with collider component). Place them on your level, then Bake the surface.